Does Agonizing Blast + Pact of the Tome AND the Sorcerer's Innate Sorcery work together?
If I was to go 2 levels into warlock to obtain Pact of the Tome (I select Sorcerous Burst) and pick this Sorcerous Burst as my Agonizing Blast warlock spell for CHA onto damage. Then could I dip a level into sorcerer to use the Innate Sorcery feature to give me advantage on my Sorcerer spells cast by me? (If this doesn't work, can I just pick Sorcerous Burst as my Sorcerer spell to get all the benefits?)

It's unlikely
First off, Eldritch Invocations are a level one feature, so no need to go 2 levels into Warlock to obtain Pact of the Tome. (Although you would need it for Agonizing Blast, if you prefer to go with the Warlock side to improve it; thanks to @TreeSpawned.)
Secondly, when you pick the cantrips for your Pact of the Tome feature, they will count as Warlock spells, not as Sorcerer spells1. The sorcerer's Innate Sorcery feature says:


You have advantage on the attack rolls of Sorcerer spells you cast.


So you won't benefit from Innate Sorcery when you cast a sorcerous burst from Pact of the Tome, as it is not a sorcerer spell for you, it is a warlock spell.
You could pick sorcerous burst as a sorcerer cantrip when you take a level of sorcerer, and then if you cast it as a sorcerer spell, it will benefit from Innate Sorcery.
What if you pick it for both classes?
You probably would not want to waste a Pact of the Tome pick on it if you get it as a sorcerer cantrip, because you always would have to choose which class feature to cast it from. It would never be both a sorcerer and a warlock spell at the same time, and benefit from both classes enhancing features to it, with the exception of counting both classes character levels. The multiclassing rules (PHB p. 44) say:

Cantrips. If a cantrip of yours increases power at higher levels, the increase is based on your total character level, not your level in a particular class, unless the spell says otherwise.

There however is no explicit statement in the multiclassing rules on which classes cantrips count towards with multiclassing, only one for prepared spells:

Each spell you prepare is associated with one of your classes, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class to cast the spell.

So until we get Sage Advice clarifications for the new edition, there is a little room for doubt; check with your DM how they want to handle it, maybe they are OK with double dipping on the benefits.

1 Pact of the Tome (p. 57, PHB) says:

When the book appears, choose three cantrips, and choose two level 1 spells. The spells can be from any class's spell list, and they must be spells you don't have already prepared. While the book is on your person, you have the chosen spells prepared, and they function as Warlock spells for you.

Does this mean you can choose only the prepared spells from any class's spell list, or also the cantrips? Cantrips are spells (of level 0), and the spellcasting rules only say about them (p. 234, PHB) "A cantrip is a spell without a spell slot", but they are listed in all class descriptions in a separate column under "Cantrips", next to a column "Prepared Spells", so they are not prepared. Technically, any cantrip therefore is a spell you have not prepared, and you should be able to choose them. But the text goes on to say that you "have the chosen spells prepared" while the book is on your person, and you could not have cantrips prepared, so this could suggest it means you cannot choose cantrips from other lists, only level 1 spells. The wording here is certainly ambiguous. However, in the previous 2014 edition, Pact of the Tome also allowed you to pick cantrips from other classes spell lists, and I think this makes it very likely that you still can do so, and pick any cantrip here, inlcuding sorcerous burst. I will assume this is how it works for the rest of the answer. With that reading, these cantrips will count as Warlock spells for you.

There is also the Eldritch Adept feat from Tasha's that lets you pick up an invocation, provided you already have one level in Warlock to meet the requirement of having Eldritch Blast (other sources dont count, per the feat), and assuming that requirement didn't change from 2014 to 2024.

@nonymous Yes, nobody (not me!) is debating that. The answer states they are level 0 spells. But if you have "the chosen spells prepared" and you cannot prepare cantrips, then one could argue that the chosen spells can be no cantrips. I do not think that is right, I think you also can pick cantrips, based on the pedigree of the ability.

The terminology around "preparing" spells has changes. All spells are prepared now.

@Nonymous Ah, I was not aware of that - there are different columns for prepared spells and cantrips in all the class descriptions, and the glossary just says "A cantrip is a level 0 spell, which is cast without a spell slot." But I think that is a fundamnetal thing to know and explain re changes, I will post a question on it.

There is no rule barring the preparation of Cantrips I can find.  Cantrips are spells that can be cast without preparation and without expending a spell slot (2024 PHB).  You can also cast a spell you have prepared (also 2024 PHB).  Quite possibly this (pact of the tome) is the only way to prepare a Cantrip in 5e.24!  Arguably the Cantrip is both known and prepared... and it is one spell, so "[it] functions as a Warlock spell[s] for you"; there is no statement that it doesn't also function as a Sorcerer spell, as you still know it as a Sorcerer class feature.

RAW, yes
With the Pact of the Tome's  Book of Shadows is on your person, you can prepare Sorcerous Burst.

...choose three cantrips, and choose two level 1 spells that have the Ritual tag. The spells can be from any class’s spell list...
While the book is on your person, you have the chosen spells prepared, and they function as Warlock spells for you.

So, you can apply Agonizing Blast to Sorcerous Burst, since it functions as one of your Warlock cantrips.
The question then becomes, is Sorcerous Burst disqualified as a sorcerer cantrip when it "functions as a Warlock cantrip" and/or is gained through another class?
While it is the case that you determine your warlock spells separately from your sorcerer spells

You determine what spells you can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class. ... Each spell you prepare is associated with one of your classes...

As written, Innate Sorcery applies to any Sorcerer Spell, which includes Sorcerous Burst. Being a member of the Sorcerer Spell List is the sufficient and necessary condition for a spell to qualify for Innate Sorcery. Therefore, gaining Sorcerous Burst through the Pact of the Tome, and casting it as a Warlock spell, do not disqualify it from Innate Sorcery
So, RAW, you can get advantage on Sorcerous Burst with Innate Sorcery and apply Agonizing Blast on a hit.

If as you quote "Each spell you prepare is associated with one of your classes", then it can't be associated with Warlock and Sorcerer at the same time.

@TreeSpawned, not quite. There are two contexts that are not mutually exclusive; it is a Warlock spell for the caster, but it is a Sorcerer spell otherwise. It needn't be "associated" in any other way, because the wording of Innate Sorcery is "Sorcerer spells you cast" not "your Sorcerer spells".

No
Pact of the Tome says the following (emphasis mine):

When the book appears, choose three cantrips, and choose two level 1 spells that have the Ritual tag. The spells can be from any class’s spell list, and they must be spells you don’t already have prepared. While the book is on your person, you have the chosen spells prepared, and they function as Warlock spells for you.

The selection of Sorcerous Burst as a cantrip can only occur if you don't already have it prepared. So if gain it as a Sorcerer to try and make this combo work, you can no longer have it from your Pact of the Tome feature.
Given the Pact of the Tome feature locks them into being a Warlock cantrip, it's not possible for Sorcerous Burst for to also be a Sorcerer spell for the purposes of qualifying for Innate Sorcery.
